# Is it a good idea to create a helper method for this type of scenario?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I have this code in my html.erb at many places.

```
<div id="left-nav">
  <%= render :partial => 'tests/tests_left_menu' %>
</div>
```

Is it a good idea to create helper method for this type of code ?

How to write this code in helper ?

Comment: Wouldn't be 'layout' better place for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few good strategies to use in your situation. Pick and choose based on your project's specific requirements.

- You can just put `div#left-nav` and its contents into yet another partial like `tests/tests_left_menu_with_wrapper`. This saves you a couple of lines.
- If you can generalize the cases when the entire segment appears, you can move it into a [layout](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html). This way, once you declare the layout for a particular action using the `ActionController::Base.layout` method, you'll be able to skip writing the entire segment altogether.
- You can write a helper, but it's not clear what advantage it confers over simply using `content_tag`. You're probably better off using partials or layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Personally i don't think there's a need to, and i think it's more like because you are not using other tools like [haml](http://haml-lang.com/) to help reduce the number of lines in an erb files

the same code can be achieved in [haml](http://haml-lang.com/) in just 1 line:

```
#left-nav= render :partial => 'tests/tests_left_menu'
```

hope this helps =)

Comment: and you save on messy closing tags ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if you have that code in many places I'd move the the `div` into the partial. If you need the flexibility to have `tests_left_menu` outside of the div I'd still pick two partials over a helper in this scenario. Avoid writing html in Ruby when you can :)